# How to produce a matrix plot from 3 matrices a, b and c following RGBColor[a[[i,j]],b[[i,j]],c[[i,j]]]?

Tags: plotting, graphics, matrix, color

I am trying to produce a single-plot from 3 matrices, let's say:

```
a = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, Nx}, {j, 1, Ny}];
b = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, Nx}, {j, 1, Ny}];
c = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, Nx}, {j, 1, Ny}];
```

The only way I know is via the following:

```
GraphicsGrid[Table[Graphics[{RGBColor[a[[i, j]], b[[i, j]], c[[i, j]]], 
Rectangle[]}], {i, 1, Nx}, {j, 1, Ny}]]
```

This gives me the following result

[image]
Does anyone could tell me how to do it using things like MatrixPlot, ArrayPlot, ColorFunction, ColorRule or any other alternative way?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as simple as

```
Nx = 10;
Ny = 10;
a = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, Nx}, {j, 1, Ny}];
b = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, Nx}, {j, 1, Ny}];
c = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, Nx}, {j, 1, Ny}];

ArrayPlot[Transpose[{a, b, c}, {3, 1, 2}], ColorFunction -> RGBColor]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can set `ColorFunction -> RGBColor` and you probably want to look into `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` for consistent results.

One thing that takes time to understand is how `Transpose` can be used to transform 3 concatenated matrices `{a,b,c}` into one matrix that has as elements triples `{aelm, belm, celm}`.

One last tip which is not as elegant as using `Transpose`, but is basically equivalent to what you are doing

```
Table[{a[[j, i]], b[[j, i]], c[[j, i]]}, {j, Ny}, {i, Nx}] // ArrayPlot
```

Comment: Beat me to it. But, I went for direct graphics generation.

Comment: Thank you (including @rcollyer) for the solutions. However, they give slightly different colours when I am using my actual matrices. The result has a white region and a red-like region (for the first solution) or pink-like region (for the second solution). My old solution, which used Graphics-like function, also gave something the pink-like version. Do you know any possible reason and interpretation? [Here you can see the difference](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sc4cxa5bvgtn1yo/se2.png?dl=0)

Comment: @PablodeCastro Have you tried setting `ColorFunction` and `ColorFunctionScaling` explicitly? I added this section to the answer. I thought that was clear and that only the transformation of the matrices was hard.

Comment: An obvious answer is the price I pay for doing things extremely tired. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Or, if you want to produce a `Graphics` directly, these produce identical results:

```
Graphics@Raster@Transpose[{a, b, c}, {3, 1, 2}]
Graphics@Raster[MapThread[List, {a, b, c}, 2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also approach this using images (rather than graphics). The command `ColorCombine` places image `a` in the red channel, `b` in the green channel, and `c` in the blue channel:

```
Nx = 10; Ny = 10;
a = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, Nx}, {j, 1, Ny}];
b = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, Nx}, {j, 1, Ny}];
c = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, Nx}, {j, 1, Ny}];
ColorCombine[{Image[a], Image[b], Image[c]}]
```

[image]

Comment: No need for `ColorCombine[]`; `Image[{a, b, c}, Interleaving -> False]` should work.